Why I get run-time and build-time version 2.42.3 even if the libwebkit2gtk-4.1.0 should already contain all the updates till version 2.46.3?
As I described in wxWidgets Forum: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=51656&start=15 I get a mismatch between Run-Time and Build-Time wxWebViewWebKit Backend only when I install in Ubuntu 24.04 the development package of libwebkit2gtk-4.1 :
After removing and cleansing everything, I installed the dev package of libwebkit2gtk-4.1:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep libwebkit2gtk
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 [installed] //  <-----------

I then downloaded wxWidgets again, configured with gtk=3, built and compiled, and installed it.
Executing webview samples in /build-gtk/samples subfolder and in /wxWidgets/samples/ folder, I got the mismatch between Run-Time and Build-Time wxWebViewWebKit Backend :
Backend: wxWebViewWebKit, run-time version=2.42.3, build-time version=2.46.1

After removing and cleansing everything, I removed the dev package of libwebkit2gtk-4.1:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep libwebkit2gtk
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 [installed]

I then downloaded wxWidgets again, configured with gtk=3, built and compiled, and installed it.
Executing webview samples in /build-gtk/samples subfolder and in /wxWidgets/samples/ folder, the Run-Time and Build-Time wxWebViewWebKit Backend
versions coincide:
Backend: wxWebViewWebKit, run-time version=2.42.3, build-time version=2.43.4

So... my First Question is:
Why does this mismatch between Run-Time and Build-Time wxWebViewWebKit Backend happen if both packages according to the official Ubuntu 24.04 repository relate to the version 2.46.1 of libwebkit2gtk ? :
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 

These are the libwebkit2gtk available in the Ubuntu 24.04 official repository:
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt-cache search libwebkit2gtk
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-doc - WebKitGTK documentation (transitional dummy package)
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0 - Web content engine library for GTK
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-dev - Web content engine library for GTK - development files
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 - Web content engine library for GTK
libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev - Web content engine library for GTK - development files

In my Ubuntu 24.04 system I have the latest version: libwebkit2gtk-4.1 :
raphy@raohy:~$ sudo apt list --installed | grep webkit2
gir1.2-webkit2-4.1/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64  
[installed,automatic]
libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0/noble-updates,now 2.46.1-0ubuntu0.24.04.1 amd64 [installed]

I'm using an x86_64(amd_64) :
raphy@raohy:~$ uname -a
Linux raohy 6.8.0-47-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Sep 27 21:40:26 UTC 
2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And the latest version of libwebkit2gtk: libwebkit2gtk-4.1, is for amd_64, the libwebkit2gtk-4.1.0 which, based on what is reported here: https://pkgs.org/download/libwebkit2gtk-4.1-0, should already contain all the updates till version 2.46.3.
So my Second Question, similar to my first question, is:
Why I get :
Backend: wxWebViewWebKit, run-time version=2.42.3, build-time version=2.42.3
even if the libwebkit2gtk-4.1.0 should already contain all the updates till version 2.46.3?
